# I was programming with node.js, and when I ran this code and an error appeared

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js, body-parser

// Error when executing:

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './types' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\vhbp2\Desktop\nodetest\node_modules\sequelize\package.json

// My Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const Post = require('./models/Post')
```

// Config

```
// Template Engine
   app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine({defaultLayout: 'main'}))
   app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
// Body Parser
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
   app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

// Rotas

```
app.get('/cad', function(req,res){
  res.render('formulario')
})

app.post('/add', function(req, res){
  Post.create({
    titulo: req.body.titulo,
    conteudo: req.body.conteudo
  }).then(function(){
    res.send("Post criado com sucesso!")
  }).catch(function(erro){
    res.send("Houve um erro: " + erro)
  })

})

app.listen(8081, function(){
console.log("Servidor Rodando na url http://localhost:8081")
});
```

Comment: You're probably using `require('sequelize/types')` somewhere. [That's not allowed in the package.json](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/0a8abbdcee501fbfde00ce2a2d922b466975a1ae/package.json#L22). Use `const {Types} = require('sequelize')`

Comment: Show `package.json`